# How to Import Excel to Database Using Laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel, import-from-excel

I need to import attendance reports to my system using Laravel Excel Library, But I have some problem with the wrong data validation. For example, I have the following excel data that I want to import into my database.
[image]

As you can see John has put his finger three times into the machine, But I want to Insert only the first and last record into my database using Laravel excel library. And also the struct of my database is like the following picture.
[image]

As you can see In my DB structure I have time_in and time_out in the same row, but in the excel file time _in is in one row, and time_out is in another row, So how I can insert this excel file correctly in my Database.

Comment: do your excel file have employee ID ?

Comment: Yes It has an Employee ID

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the data before sending it to the Database (DB), not just directly feed it to your DB.
A simple `explode` with `' '` as the separator can split the `Date/Time` column then use `DateTime` to format the date and time, meanwhile keep tracking which of the data you need as `Time In` and `Time Out`

Assuming:
`$date = explode(' ',$dateTime);`

`$date[0] = the date, 2/1/2021`
`$date[1] = the time, 7:31`

Assuming the date is `j/n/Y`,
`attendance_date` can be filled as `$attDate = date_format(DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/Y', trim($date[0]),'Y-m-d');`

Comment: I know how to explode date and time, But here is another problem that I discussed. First, as I discussed the problem there is that I want to insert two rows of Excel file into one row of my Database. I want to insert one row as Time IN and another row as Time Out.

Answer (score -2):

may be you have to parse data before store it into database
or your can change the Excel file contents

Comment: This better belongs as a comment, rather than being submitted as an answer.

Comment: 50 reputation is required to comment so that why I answered

Comment: Sorry Brother I can not change the excel file, because It is an attendance report that I export from the Fingerprint machine every day and there is no such time to edit that file every day.